# Constraint not satisfied

Tags: openmdao

I am using openMDAO version 1.7.1, ScipyOptimizer, SLSQP, fd, step_size 1.0e-4.

I scaled design variables to [0, 1] and got converged results with design variables within their ranges. However, one constraint is still not satisfied. I set a constraint for a parameter to be [0, 1.5], but the final result is 1.73, for example. I tried two different convergence error limits, 0.01 and 0.001, but this constraint was not satisfied.

Any ideas about why this thing happened? Am I doing settings wrong? possible bugs? if not, how to avoid?

Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Is the optimizer reporting in its output (set 'disp' to True in the options) that the constraint is violated and the optimization was unsuccessful? If so, then the optimizer couldn't solve the problem for some reason. It could be an error in calculations for a component the model, or it could just be that this problem that isn't well-posed for this optimizer. Would have to see the problem to understand more.

With a gradient optimizer like SLSQP, sometimes the problem is an error in the derivative calculations. There are a couple of tools that you can use to help find mistakes in the component derivatives:

```
prob.check_partial_derivatives()
```

This loops over all components in your model and compares the analytic derivatives with finite difference.

```
prob.check_total_derivatives()
```

This calcualtes the total derivatives of all objectives and constraints wrt the design variables and compares them with full-model finite difference.

Note that you have to keep in mind the limitations of finite difference accuracy when evaluating if you have a mistake in the analytics.

Comment: Hi Kenneth, thank you for the comments and suggestions. I did not set 'disp' to True, and I am re-running the codes with True now, and hopefully get results several days later. However, I saw the optimization stopped with these information: "positive directional derivative for linesearch (exit mode 8), iterations: 8, function evaluations: 13, gradient evaluations: 4, optimization complete". Is exit mode 8 an indication of failure? Thanks.

Comment: That is definitely an optimization failure. Basically it couldn't find anywhere to go. If you are providing anallytic derivatives in your components, then there might be an error in the derivs, and you can find it with the functions I mentioned above. Beyond that, there could also be a scaling problem if you have design variables with magnitudes that differ by wide margins, you want to get them scaled down to the same order of magnitude. The same thing applies to your constraints too.

Answer (score 0):

I walk down the same road with a problem of mine. After checking derivatives as suggested (and indeed fixing some errors), I still got convergence issue and finally change of the optimizer (pyOptSparse(SLSQP) in my case) or even just use of a different initial point worked for me.

Comment: Yeah, SLSQP in general is a bit of a weak optimizer. SNOPT is 10000x better, but its not open source. We commonly use SNOPT internally for almost any sqp application though.